# Create two table vertically aligned

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have tables in HTML

I want the second headings below to be aligned with the first headings vertically along with the other tables below the second heading but I can't find a right way to do it, I've searched some information on the internet but still doesn't worked.

Here is my sample html code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http=equiv="content-Type" content="text/html; charset-utf-8"/>
        <title>Payments</title>
    </head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #wrap {
            width: 460px;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <h5 style="text-align:left"></br></br>PROVIDENCE 
            MEMORIAL PARK-SAN JOSE DEL MONTE BULACAN <p></p>
            OFFICIAL PRICE LIST effective May 10, 2013</h5> 
    </body>
    <table border="$" cellpadding="10" width="400">
        <tr>
            <th>Lot type</td>
            <th>Lot price</td>
            <th>Mem'rl maintenance fund</td>
            <th>Total price</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table border="$" cellpadding="10" width="400" >
        <tr>
            LAWN LOT 1 (Reflection of Life & Evergreen 

            Mem'ries)
            <td height="20">Regular</td>
            <td height="20">40,000.00</td>
            <td height="20">4,500.00</td>
            <td height="20">44,500.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Special</td>
            <td>42,000.00</td>
            <td>4,500.00</td>
            <td>46,500.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Premium</td>
            <td>46,000.00</td>
            <td>4,500.00</td>
            <td>50,500.00</td>
        </tr>
    </tr>
</table>
<table border="$" cellpadding="10" width="400">
    <tr>
        LAWN 2 LOTS (Eternal Devotion)
        <td>Regular</td>
        <td>87,000.00</td>
        <td>10,000.00</td>
        <td>97,000.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Special</td>
        <td>93,000.00</td>
        <td>10,000.00</td>
        <td>103,000.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Premium</td>
        <td>98,000.00</td>
        <td>10,000.00</td>
        <td>10,000.00</td>
    </tr>
</tr>
</table>
<table border="$" cellpadding="10" width="400">
    <tr>
        COURT 4 LOTS (Court of serenity)
        <td>Regular</td>
        <td>157,000.00</td>
        <td>20,000.00</td>
        <td>177,000.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Special</td>
        <td>168,000.00</td>
        <td>20,000.00</td>
        <td>188,000.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Premium</td>
        <td>180,000.00</td>
        <td>20,000.00</td>
        <td>200,000.00</td>
    </tr>
</tr>
</table>
<table border="$" cellpadding="10" width="400">
    <tr style="margin-top:10px;"></tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Lot type</td>
        <th>Lot price</td>
        <th>Mem'rl maintenance fund</td>
        <th>Total price</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table border="$" cellpadding="10" width="400">
    <tr>
        COURT 8 LOTS  (Court of tranquility)
        <td>Regular</td>
        <td>348,000.00</td>
        <td>40,000.00</td>
        <td>388,000.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Special</td>
        <td>369,000.00</td>
        <td>40,000.00</td>
        <td>409,000.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Premium</td>
        <td>392,000.00</td>
        <td>40,000.00</td>
        <td>432,000.00</td>
    </tr>
</tr>
</table>
<table border="$" cellpadding="10" width="400">
    <tr>
        ESTATE 12 LOTS (Piety Estate)
        <td>Premium</td>
        <td>646,000.00</td>
        <td>60,000.00</td>
        <td>706,000.00</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table border="$" cellpadding="10" width="400">
    <tr>
        ESTATE 18 LOTS (Harmony Estate)
        <td>Premium</td>
        <td>968,000,00</td>
        <td>90,000,00</td>
        <td>1,058,000.00</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table border="$" cellpadding="10" width="400">
    <tr>
        ESTATE 24 LOTS (Solace Estate)
        <td>Premium</td>
        <td>1,218,000.00</td>
        <td>120,000.00</td>
        <td>1,388,000.00</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated :)

Comment: HTML documents can only have **ONE** `<body>`. Your html is flat-out invalid - you cannot have any "content" outside of `<body>`.

Comment: I'm learning HTML as a beginner, thanks for the information there are still many things I don't know about HTML :)

Comment: @user2123999 Could you explain your goal/problem a bit more concisely?

Comment: @tiny I want to have two tables with the same headings and aligned them vertically..

Comment: @tiny dividing my table into two. I can't post an image here.Sorry, my question is a little but confusing.

Comment: @user2123999 I would suggest [validating your markup](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) before moving forward

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/WX7Yg/).

CSS

```
table {
    width: 500px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td, th {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I won't repeat the HTML here, but the teaching points are:

Once you get a table put together (structure and content), style it with CSS.

All `<td>`'s should end with `</td>`'s.

All `<th>`'s should end with `</th>`'s.

`<td colspan='4'></td>` Will give you a single  that is 4 columns wide.